# Converting JSON String to Dictionary in (Python)

Tags: python

i have a following json file

json_data = {
                 "action":"postRecord", 
                 "data":{
                     "data":[
                         {
                              "info":{
                                    "lid":999,
                                    "cid":1234
                          },
                              "info":{
                                    "lid":111,
                                    "cid":"6789"
                           }
                     }
                 ]
            } 
         }

i tried the usage of json.load

output = json.load(json_data)
but it returnign a string 
i want to access the value of id in a way like output['data']['data']['info']['id']

Comment: `json.load(json_data) ` would not even run

Comment: Is that the content of your json file? If so, it's not valid json. Or do you want json_data to be a string that is valid json? Then you need it to be string (`'{ "action": "postRecord" [....] }'`, note the outer `''`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't your data already in the format you want?

```
print json_data['data']['data'][0]['info']['cid']
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh. You're saying that you've got an JSON array as a plain text in a `json_data` variable?

You should put the JSON data into the `json_data` variable as a string and use `json.loads(json_data)`.

Since JSON is just text, you should treat it like a string, unless you have opened a JSON file from the disk, then `json.load()` should work with the file object itself.

```
In [5]: json_data = '{ "action":"postRecord", "data":{ "data":[ { "info":{ "lid":999, "cid":1234 }, "info":{ "lid":111, "cid":"6789" } } ] } }'

In [6]: output = json.loads(json_data)

In [7]: output['data']['data'][0]['info']['cid']
Out[7]: u'6789'
```

Answer (score 0):

seems the original json string has problem, there has duplicate info property in one element, so after json.dump to format , the first info will be removed , and the result is the second 6789.

```
json_data = { "action":"postRecord", "data":{ "data":[ { "info":{ "lid":999, "cid":1234 }, "info":{ "lid":111, "cid":"6789" } } ] } }
data = json.dumps(json_data)
json_to_python = json.loads(data)
print (json_to_python)
print (json_to_python['data']['data'][0]['info']['cid'])

======>
{'action': 'postRecord', 'data': {'data': [{'info1': {'lid': 999, 'cid': 1234}, 'info': {'lid': 111, 'cid': '6789'}}]}}
6789
```